# TypeScript: why I cannot remove this type assertion?

Tags: typescript, types, casting

Why this piece of code won't compile?

```
interface TaggedProduct {
    tag: string;
}
interface Product {
    tag?: string;
}
const tagProduct = (product: Product): TaggedProduct => {
    const tag: string = "anything";
    product.tag = tag;

    // Type 'Product' is not assignable to type 'TaggedProduct'.
    // Property 'tag' is optional in type 'Product' but required in type 'TaggedProduct'.ts(2322)
    return product; // Won't compile
}
```

I would think that if you add a `tag` field to a `Product`, you necessarily have a `TaggedProduct`. Why does TypeScript think otherwise? Can I get around this without a type assertion?

Comment: you are returning product, not TaggedProduct and that is the main issue. the product param passed in is assigned a tag property and although this is only optional in your Interface, it is of course legal. Then you return that same product.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.assign` to avoid a type assertion:

```
const tagProduct = (product: Product): TaggedProduct => {
  const tag: string = "anything";
  return Object.assign(product, {tag});
}
```

This is because `Object.assign` is typed like this:

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
  assign<T, U>(target: T, source: U): T & U;
}
```

and so the return type of `Product & {tag: string}` is assignable to `TaggedProduct`.